# Livereload only on changes in public folder

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I'm using Grunt to watch for changes in my sass/js files and the compile them into my public folder. I've setup a Livereload feature that's working fine but when I compile my js the Livereload reloads my page 2 times which is annoying. I think this is because I have multiple JS files that are created during the watch (concat, minify).

So I thought it might be a good idea to only reload on changes in my public folder since (for now) I only have one js file (uglify.js) and one css file (main.css). But I can't see how I can get that working.

This is how my current gruntfile looks:

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {

        // Project configuration.
        grunt.initConfig({
            watch: {
                watch_js_files: {
                    files: ['js/*.js'],
                    tasks: ['concat', 'minified', 'uglify'],
                },
                watch_sass_files: {
                    files: ['css/*.scss'],
                    tasks: ['sass'],
                }
            },
            connect: {
                server: {
                    options: {
                        open: true,
                        keepalive: true,
                        hostname: 'localhost',
                        port: 8080,
                        base: ''
                    }
                }
            },
            concat: {
                dist: {
                    src: ['js/*.js'],
                    dest: 'js/min/concat.js'
                },
            },
            minified: {
                files: {
                    src: ['js/min/concat.js'],
                    dest: 'js/min/minified.js'
                },
            },
            uglify: {
                my_target: {
                    files: {
                        'public/js/uglify.js': ['js/min/minified.jsconcat.js']
                    }
                }
            },
            sass: {
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'public/css/main.css': 'css/*.scss'
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-minified');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a reload task in my watch:

```
        reload: {
            files: ['*.html', 'public/css/*.css', 'public/js/*.js'],
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 35729,
            }
        },
```

And now it works :)